# How to use Pandas to calculate cross points and its date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following sample data which has **date** and **value** columns. The **cross_date_since** column is my expected result. The value of **value** is ranging from 0 to 1. If the value is higher/lower than 0.5, the **cross_date_since** should be its first date of crossing up/down.

I tried to use apply() and loop-and-loop to do that. They work but very slow if the data is large. Is there any efficient way to solve this problem?

```
date      value  *cross_date_since*
2021-07-01   0.48   2021-07-01
2021-07-02   0.88   2021-07-02
2021-07-03   0.7    2021-07-02
2021-07-04   0.65   2021-07-02  
2021-07-05   0.46   2021-07-05
2021-07-06   0.22   2021-07-05
2021-07-07   0.32   2021-07-05 
2021-07-08   0.33   2021-07-05    
2021-07-09   0.54   2021-07-09 
2021-07-10   0.66   2021-07-09
2021-07-11   0.65   2021-07-09
2021-07-12   0.75   2021-07-09
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out the cross date and fill the corresponding values first and then do a forward fill with `ffill`:

```
df.loc[df.value.gt(0.5).diff().fillna(True), 'cross_date_since'] = df.date

df
#          date  value cross_date_since
#0   2021-07-01   0.48       2021-07-01
#1   2021-07-02   0.88       2021-07-02
#2   2021-07-03   0.70              NaN
#3   2021-07-04   0.65              NaN
#4   2021-07-05   0.46       2021-07-05
#5   2021-07-06   0.22              NaN
#6   2021-07-07   0.32              NaN
#7   2021-07-08   0.33              NaN
#8   2021-07-09   0.54       2021-07-09
#9   2021-07-10   0.66              NaN
#10  2021-07-11   0.65              NaN
#11  2021-07-12   0.75              NaN

df.cross_date_since.ffill(inplace=True)
df
#          date  value cross_date_since
#0   2021-07-01   0.48       2021-07-01
#1   2021-07-02   0.88       2021-07-02
#2   2021-07-03   0.70       2021-07-02
#3   2021-07-04   0.65       2021-07-02
#4   2021-07-05   0.46       2021-07-05
#5   2021-07-06   0.22       2021-07-05
#6   2021-07-07   0.32       2021-07-05
#7   2021-07-08   0.33       2021-07-05
#8   2021-07-09   0.54       2021-07-09
#9   2021-07-10   0.66       2021-07-09
#10  2021-07-11   0.65       2021-07-09
#11  2021-07-12   0.75       2021-07-09
```

Comment: I don't even know ffill this method which can propagate last value. I had some problems like this before and I used stupid logic to do that. Thank you so much. Great help to me.